# Writing the contents of an array to another file?

Tags: php, http, get, paypal, fwrite

I'm attempting to test out the PayPal IPN, so I want to set-up a script to write all the contents of the `$_GET` array to a file, so I can see if what is requested is as I assume.

However, I'm having trouble configuring the file to actually display the contents of the array as though it were being dumped.

**For example:**

```
$string = $_GET;

$fp = fopen("paypal_req.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
```

Simply echo's the value of `$_GET` into the file `paypal_req.txt`, which of course is `Array`.

How could I have the contents of the array `$_GET` dumped into `paypal_req.txt` as though I were using `var_dump()`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = print_r($_GET, true);
```

Comment: Props. I always use `var_dump()` which offers no return parameter, just checked the doc now :). I'll accept when the timer drops!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a similar output to var_dump(), you can use the var_export() function:

```
$string = var_export($_GET, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `var_export($_GET, true)` suggestion is the best, but you *could* use var_dump by capturing its output with output buffering.

```
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($_GET);
$dump = ob_get_clean();
?>
```